# Execute Luakit browser commands from shell script

Tags: html, shell, browser

I wrote unix shell script that is doing this:

1. show local .html file with animation inside luakit browser,
2. sleep 4 seconds,
3. show .mp4 video with omx player,
4. show local .html file with animation inside luakit browser,
5. sleep 4 seconds,
6. show .mp4 video with omx player,
7. and so on and so on

Transition from .html file to video is nice, but from video to .html file is NOT because after .mp4 video ends, luakit is showing previously opened .html file and then it opens new tab and shows me second .html file, and I would like that luakit opens next .html file inside current tab and not new one. Any way to do this ?

Also is there any way to execute luakit browser commands from shell script because I tried to execute many of them inside script but not a single one works. For example, if you press "d" it key closes current tab and if I could archieve that I would just close current tab and open new .html file normaly.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Show us the code you are using instead of just describing what you are doing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. So basicly, I had to install "xdotool" to simulate keyboard input, binded "d" key in my "binds.lua" file so when I press "d" on keyboard I close current tab but browser remains open. Simplified shell script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
setterm -cursor off

luakit myHtmlFile1.html &
sleep 4;
echo "FINISHED WITH 1ST .HTML FILE"
xdotool key "d"

omxplayer myVideo.mp4
clear
echo "FINISHED WITH .MP4 VIDEO"

luakit myHtmlFile2.html &
sleep 4;
echo "FINISHED SCRIPT"
```

Transition from video to .html file is very good and it doesn't have interupts like before. Later, I will change script so it will play all files in some directory in infinite loop. Because of that I think best method is to close current tab, so you don't have to worry about memory issues and unnecessary tab stockpiling, specially on low-level memory computers like Raspberry Pi.